# defaultProtocol not working for links with ckeditor5-vue

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor, vue-component, ckeditor5

Vue component

```
<ckeditor :editor="classiceditor" v-model="report_notes" :config="editorConfig" @blur="editReportNotes()" @keyup.enter="editReportNotes()"></ckeditor>
```

vuejs code

```
    classiceditor:ClassicEditor,
    editorConfig: {
        // plugins: [ Underline],
        toolbar: {
            items: [
                'bold','italic',
                '|','link',
                '|','bulletedList', 'numberedList',
            ]
        },
        placeholder :'Write a note...',
        link: {
            defaultProtocol: 'http://'
        }
    },
```

Issue is defaultProtocal is not setting. when i give gogole.com as link, It is opening as my-domain/google.com which is a non existing page

I need it as http://google.com

I followed this doc [defaultProtocal](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_link_link-LinkConfig.html#member-defaultProtocol)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re-installeed and Upgraded from version 16.0.0 to 22.0.0. Because the feature is recently added

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```